# Получить строку по схождению

Tags: c#, строки

У меня такая проблема. Есть список игроков, точнее их имена. Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было получить целое имя не вводя его полностью.
Например:
Есть имя:

```
Маша
```

Я введу Ма, и оно должно найти Машу.
Пробывал через Contains,но оно находит любое имя в котором есть Ма.
Спасибо

Comment: `String.StartsWith` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Igor мож ответом?

Comment: -1 за слово "Пробывал"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
string[] names = new string[] { "Маруся", "Даша", "Маша", "Каша" };
string str = "Ма";
var similar = names.Where(item => item.StartsWith(str));
```